# Umbraco Child Level Count

Tags: view, nodes, umbraco7

Is it possible to return the total number of node levels beneath a given page in a view? It's possible loop through the child nodes (ex: the descendants partial), but is it possible to get the total child levels?

Getting the first level is simple:

```
var naviLevel = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible").First().Level;
```

Is it possible to count all levels without having to @foreach through the remaining child pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this......

```
@{

   var list = new List<int>();
   var currentPage = Model;

    foreach (var child in currentPage.Descendants())
    {
        int level = Convert.ToInt32(child.Level);
        list.Add(level);
    }

    var levelCount = list.Distinct().Max();    

    <h2>@levelCount</h2>

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I was hoping there'd be a .Level.Count() or something short. I ended up just adding a bool property to the document types at the node level I was attempting to find.